# .addEventListener throwing TypeError

Tags: javascript

I am setting up a function that will close a dropdown menu when clicked outside. The function works as intended, however it throws a error.

I am not sure what is causing the error, considering that the function works as intended.

```
const userBtn = document.querySelector(".header-userbtn");
const userMenu = document.querySelector(".header-usermenu");

function hideOnClickOutside(element, button) {
  if (!element.classList.contains("active")) {
    return false;
  }
  const outsideClickListener = event => {
    if (!element.contains(event.target)) {
      button.click();
      removeClickListener();
    }
  };

  const removeClickListener = () => {
    document.removeEventListener("click", outsideClickListener);
  };

  document.addEventListener("click", outsideClickListener);
}

userBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const chevron = this.querySelector(".chevron-wht");

  this.classList.toggle("active");
  chevron.classList.toggle("active");
  userMenu.classList.toggle("active");

  e.stopPropagation();
  document.addEventListener(             /*main.js:31 */
    "click",
    hideOnClickOutside(userMenu, userBtn));
});
```

Here is the Error Message. It triggers every time the menu closes, and the function is called from the click event.

```
main.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': The callback provided as parameter 2 is not an object.
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:31)
```

Answer (score 1):

you aren't currently providing a callback function to your specified event listener...

```js
document.addEventListener(
    "click",
    function() { hideOnClickOutside(userMenu, userBtn); }
 );
```